# Split up answers to FAQ questions

Tags: feature-request, meta-faq

We have quite a few [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) here on meta where multiple "sub-questions" elaborate on the main FAQ.

The format of a lot of these is that one answer is posted with all the sub-questions and their answers listed.

This is a little inconvenient, both because it's hard to navigate right off the bat (if I want to go to a specific sub-question/answer combination, I need to scroll and find it or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> it) and it makes it hard to direct users to a specific question/answer combination when necessary.

I suggest that we split up these one-answer FAQs and make each sub-question/answer combo into a separate answer to the question post. Then we can link to the individual answers instead of the one, which will be especially convenient if we want to direct users to a specific part.

(The one that sparked this suggestion was [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), the one for the bounty system. That single answer is especially bulky so it would be nice to have it split up.)

This is my vision (and forgive the off font):

[image: blah]

This is supposed to simulate my vision of the answers for the bounty FAQ. Notice that each of these answers is a part of the single large answer in the FAQ's current form.

We already have this linking functionality in `/faq`, why not have it in the meta faqs?

Comment: I can appreciate wanting a specific anchor to link to, but a dozen different answers on that question seems a bit overkill -- reading it as a consistent whole would be more difficult, imho.

Comment: Hmm. I'm a bit torn - on one hand, I can see how linking to individual answers would be handy. On the other, voting would screw up the order and possibly make it harder to follow the page as a whole.

Comment: I honestly can't understand what you're suggesting here. Do you want to break up, for example, [the answers to the questions listed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/153008) into separate questions, each with their own answers? Do you want to just add *links* to those sub-questions in the question itself? Do you want to consolidate all answers to [all the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) questions onto that single page, posting them as answers? ...or something else entirely?

Comment: @CodyGray: I want to split up the answers listed there into what they are: answers. I want there to be entirely separate answers instead of that one answer with all the others grouped together. My image explains it pretty well.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I'm glad you see it the way I see it. The voting wouldn't be a problem, I think--users could just click the "oldest" tab and get the answers in descending order of when they were posted (we would do it strategically, to post the one that came first in the list as the first answer, and so on).